# Second-Order, Linear Inhomogeneous Recurrence Relation With Constant Coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, homogeneous-equation

How does one solve the general recurrence relation
$$s_n=\alpha s_{n-1}+\beta s_{n-2}+\zeta(n)?$$

Comment: Do you have an explicit formula for $\zeta$?  Do you know about solving linear difference equations with constant coefficients?  The process is quite similar to solving differential equations.

Comment: [This PDF](http://www.ee.ntu.edu.tw/~yen/courses/dm-s2012/Chap05.pdf) gives one method; the section on non-homogeneous recurrences starts halfway through, on page $15$.

Comment: $\zeta$ is either a constant, $n$, or $n^2$.

Answer (score 1):

A particular solution of the difference equation
$$s_n=\alpha s_{n-1}+\beta s_{n-2}+a+bn+cn^2\qquad(n\geq2)$$
can be found with the "Ansatz"
$$s_n=A+Bn+Cn^2,\tag{1}$$
and solving for $A$, $B$, $C$ by comparing coefficients. If $\alpha+\beta\ne1$, i.e.,if the associated homogeneous problem 
$$s_n=\alpha s_{n-1}+\beta s_{n-2}\tag{2}$$ has no constant solutions, there will be exactly one admissible triple $(A,B,C)$.

Then solve the homogeneous problem $(2)$ in the usual way and add its general solution $n\mapsto C_1\lambda^n +C_2 \mu^n$ to the particular solution $(1)$ constructed before. Finally fix $C_1$ and $C_2$ using the initial conditions.

The cases $\alpha+\beta=1$ and $\lambda=\mu$ require special consideration, but lead to similar results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a foolproof approach. The difference equation is second order so we'll need two initial values, say $s_0,s_1$.

Let $S(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_nx^n$. Similarly, $Z(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \zeta(n)$. Then

$$s_{n}x^n=\alpha s_{n-1}x^n+\beta s_{n-2}x^n+\zeta(n)x^n$$

summing this from $n=2$ to $\infty$ gives:

$$S(x)-s_1x+s_0=\alpha x(S(x)-s_0)+\beta x^2 S(x)+Z(x)-\zeta(1)x-\zeta(0).$$

Solving this for $S(x)$ gives:

$$S(x)=\frac{Z(x)-\zeta(1)x-\zeta(0)-(1+\alpha x)s_0+s_1x}{1-\alpha x-\beta x^2}$$

meaning that

$$s_n(x)=\left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}S(x)\right|_{x=0},$$

or just reading off the $x^n$ coefficient. If $\zeta(n)=n$ or $n^2$, then $Z(x)=x/(1-x)^2$ or $Z(x)=-x(x-1)/(1-x)^3$.
I'll leave the pleasure of figuring out the exact coefficients to you. You can save yourself some time by using partial fractions on the expression for $S(x)$ and then use the known nice generating functions like $1/(1-x)=1+x+x^2$, or [Newton's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem) for $1/(1-x)^s$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The command of Maple `rsolve({s(n) = alpha*s(n-1)+beta*s(n-2)+Zeta(n)}, s)` produces a long answer which can be seen in the worksheet exported as [a PDF file](http://rapidshare.com/files/648534046/rsolve.pdf). For example, in the concrete case $$ rsolve({s(1) = 1, s(2) = 1, s(n) = s(n-1)+s(n-2)+Zeta(n)}, s)$$  the answer is $$ -1/5\,\sqrt {5} \left( -1/2\,\sqrt {5}+1/2 \right) ^{n}+1/5\,\sqrt {5}
 \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {5}+1/2 \right) ^{n}+
$$ $$\sum_{n0=3}^n 2/5\,\sqrt {5} \left( -2\, \left( \sqrt {5}+1 \right) ^{-1} \right) ^{
n-{\it n0}} \left( \sqrt {5}+1 \right) ^{-1}\zeta(n0)-
 $$ $$\sum_{n0=3}^n 2/5\,\sqrt {5} \left( -2\, \left( -\sqrt {5}+1 \right) ^{-1} \right) ^
{n-{\it n0}} \left( -\sqrt {5}+1 \right) ^{-1}\zeta(n0)
 $$

Answer (score 0):

Write your recurrence so there are no index subtractions (my $\zeta$ isn't yours, sorry):
$$
s_{n + 2} = \alpha s_{n + 1} + \beta s_n + \zeta(n)
$$
Define $S(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n$ (I'm assuming the recurrence is valid from $n = 0$ on, adjust as required). Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize the resulting sums:
$$
\frac{S(z) - s_0 - s_1 z}{z^2}
  = \alpha \frac{S(z) - s_0}{z} + \beta S(z)
      + \sum_{n \ge 0} \zeta(n) z^n
$$
The last sum you'd have to get somehow. Typical seasonings are:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} a^n z^n
  &= \frac{1}{1 - a z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} k u_n z^n
  &= z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} U(z) 
       \qquad U(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} u_n z^n \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} \left( \sum_{0 \le k \le n} u_k \right) z^n
  &= \frac{U(z)}{1 - z}
\end{align}
Sometimes you recognize a Cauchy product:
$$
U(z) \cdot V(z)
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} \left( \sum_{0 \le k \le n} u_k v_{n - k} \right) z^n
$$
(particular cases to look out for are $u_k = a^k$, or some other simple form).

Solve the resulting equation for $S(z)$, split into partial fractions. Most of the time use of the generalized binomial theorem allows to read off the coefficients, if they aren't just geometric series:
$$
(1 + x)^{- m}
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-m}{k} x^k
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1} x^k
$$
For qualitative/order of magnitude results, note that $\binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1}$ is just a polynomial of degree $m - 1$ in $k$